# How to update secret string using cludformation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am a newbie to AWS cloudformation, any help will appreciated.
I have a use case wherein I would like to write CFN to update already existing secret string. I was able to find a CFN to create a secret string but not to update.

I see the AWS CLI has `aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id` I was looking for similar option in Cloudformation.

Answer (score 0):

Use cloud formation template for create secret but instead of creating stack, update the existing stack using change set.
but do it you must know the stack name which is created before to create secrets.

may be use the same template which used earlier just change the value and update stack